# twitter bootstrap datetimepicker does not show up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am trying to use the bootstrap date time picker from here:
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

But I just cannot seem to get the simple example running. When I click on the calendar glyph, nothing happens, I would expect datetime picker to show up!
 Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template for bootstrap</title>
    <link href="dependencies/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dependencies/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dependencies/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
          });

        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dependencies/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dependencies/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Edit 1: I have also tried calling timepicker function after included js libs and before body end tag, but no success.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dependencies/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dependencies/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the timepicker function _after_ the included the JS libraries, right before the body end tag?

Comment: I have tried it now, but no success.

Comment: could you post a link to your site?

Comment: Your code is working correctly Check http://jsfiddle.net/MqM6t/

Comment: @domdev I was trying this on my pc, so no external link to it!

Comment: @Manish - Thanks for that. I can see it is running fine on fiddle, but does not work on my pc! Is there a chance you can copy that html and run it on your pc to check?

Comment: thanks- I think it was that I right click on bootstrap-datepicker css and js files by right clicking in github, which basically gave me an html and not really the js and css file. Now by getting just css and js contents, I am able to run it fine! Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 to both on commenting

Comment: @GabbarSingh I'm the maintainer of that plugin (and recently rewrote it to use momentjs). Did you get your issue resolved?

Comment: @Eonasdan : hiya, yes I had to download moment.js to make it work. Though I was adamant about not downloading it as the instructions did not say it needed moment.js. But in the end I downloaded it and it runs fine now. Thanks.

Comment: V2 does require it. It's listed first thing on the github page. V1 is still available under the [version1 branch](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/version1). I try to stay on top of the issues list so don't hesitate to create an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the resources are correctly linked, download and replace the resources from external link and use it. Try this code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template for bootstrap</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/styles/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, I just found that, but +1 for your comprehensive reply which others will definitely find useful.

Comment: version 2, to which you are hot linking to, required momentjs. This code will not work